# understanding streamreader and internalbuffer?

Tags: c#

I have a .txt file that has 3 lines as following:

A50

B25

C25

This is my code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"E:\1.txt", FileMode.Open);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
textBox1.AppendText(sr.ReadLine() + "\r\n");
textBox1.AppendText(fs.Position.ToString());
```

now after running the above code,the output will be:

A50

14

My question is why the position value is 14? why it's not 4 as pointer of the stream would point to '\n' character that is at the end of the first line A50?Is this related to internalbuffer?and what's internalbuffer in detail and how it is work with streamreader?

sorry for bad english.

Comment: Note that even if `StreamReader` didn't read any extra data, the file position would still be at least 8 because each character occupies two bytes, not one. Are you sure you want bytes and not chars? (Chars take 2 bytes - which is the default- unless you're using ASCII or ANSI text.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Chars *might* take more than one byte each. You mentioned ASCII and ANSI. Although there is no ANSI encoding, there are *many* 8-bit encodings. And a single character in UTF-8 could be anywhere from 1 to 7 bytes long. Saying "each character occupies two bytes" is only correct for a relatively small number of encodings.

Comment: @JimMischel Nevertheless, if you look at the actual code that the OP posted, you can see that the he is using the default encoding, so it will definitely be at least 2 bytes per character. The point I was making is that it's (at least) 2 bytes per character for the *default* encoding, and that's important.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: The default encoding for `StreamReader` is `Utf8Encoding`, which is a variable-length encoding. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at.aspx. Most Western European text will be one byte per character. So the text in the file on the disk will most likely be one byte per character. Of course, *everything* is two bytes per code point internally.

Comment: @JimMischel Doh, of course it is. Sorry - I'm clearly suffering brain fade! :)

Answer (score 4):

The `StreamReader` reads data from the disk into an internal buffer and then satisfies requests from that buffer.

It works that way in order to reduce the number of times it has to call the operating system for data. If it didn't have an internal buffer, then it would have to do this:

```
while (not end-of-file and character != newline)
{
    read next character and append to string
}
```

With the internal buffer, it reads a big chunk of data (default is something like 4K bytes, but that can be changed) into memory. Then it can quickly scan that block of data for a newline character and return the string.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why the position value is 14?

The `StreamReader` has "overread" in order to perform relatively few read operations on the underlying stream. Yes, it's related to the internal buffer - the idea is that it will perform "chunky" read operations on the underlying stream, often reading more than it strictly needs to in order to satisfy the current operation - thus preventing lots of single-byte reads.

To read a line at a time with no risk of over-reading, it would have to read a single *byte* at a time - which might not even be a single character. Depending on the stream implementation, this may well be inefficient. Instead, it reads into a buffer which is a hidden implementation detail (you don't have direct access to the buffer) and then satisfies requests from that buffer until it has to read from the stream again.

Comment: Is there any way so that I can read a file in single-byte manner?

Comment: @AbdulwadoudTah You don't need StreamReader for that; you can just use [`FileStream.ReadByte()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readbyte.aspx) You sure you don't need to read chars rather than bytes though?

Comment: @AbdulwadoudTah: Why do you want to? What's the bigger picture here?